# How to use ArrayList two-input method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of 5 cards and I need to modify my **addCard method** so that it looks for the 1st card in my hand which value is less than Card c. Then I have to use `void add( int index, E x )` and plug in the Card c in my hand at that index.

`getValue()` is a method of finding the pip value of the cards

`private ArrayList<Card> myHand;` is an ArrayList, and Card is a class.

I'm just confused as how to use the add method, here's my attempt.

```
// Insert definitions for the getCardValue and addCard methods here
public int getCardValue(int n) {
    return myHand.get(n).getValue();
}

public void addCard(Card c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        while (myHand.get(i).getValue() < myHand.get(c).getValue())
            myHand.add(i, c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Card[] cards = { new Card("spades", 4), new Card("hearts", 10),
                    new Card("clubs", 12), new Card("diamonds", 14),
                    new Card("diamonds", 2) };
    Hand h = new Hand();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        h.addCard(cards[i]);
    System.out.println(h.getCardValue(3));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you've shown your attempt... but you haven't told us what happens with it. (It's not clear what you expect `myHand.get(c)` to do, either... or what the type of `myHand` is, even.)

Comment: `public void add(int index,
       E element)`

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Comment: @JonSkeet Since there's 5 cards, I tried to go through them and see where the Card c will be bigger than it, and then replace that card in my hand with the Card c

Comment: You might be better off using [`ListIterator.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)). Although it is somewhat unclear what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Oninez: That doesn't answer what you expect `myHand.get(c)` to do. Think about that specific question. You also still haven't said what happens with your current code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints